# possible to share task within jobs in Azure Devops pieline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

We have a parallel jobs like

1. Job: Website
2. Job: Website.Test

But there's one step/task need to be shared in both jobs, is there a way we can achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Copy/paste? What do you mean by "shared"?

Comment: @jessehouwing - sonarcloudprepare task -  this step is needed for both website and website.test to get code analysis and code coverage

Comment: Declare it twice.

Comment: @jessehouwing - Then there's no mean left for parallel jobs as both are taking almost same amount of time

Comment: If you want to set the settings once, you'll need to create a yaml-template, include that into your workflow and use the template to run the step: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops

Comment: As far as I know, you can't run the Sonar Init task in a separate job from the one that processes the results. So the only optimization you can do here is using a template to not have to duplicate the configuration. In my eyes, that's just too much work for too little benefit.

Comment: But I still don't fully understand what it is you're trying to accomplish. Do you want a cleaner YAML file? Do you want a faster build? Do you want one sonar project, but multiple sources reporting into it? What is working so far? What isn't? What have you tried?

Comment: @jessehouwing - We've a build pipeline which contain website and website.test , there's a SonarCloudPreparaStep for code analysis and coverage but the problem is as soon as we enable that step our build time increases from 2 min to almost 30 min and we still waiting from them for any resolution. Therefore we thought to split Website and Website.Test into two parallel jobs but found that SonarCloudPreparaStep is required in both to get code analysis and coverage but adding it to website.test step is taking higher build time so just want to run it once and share it with both

Comment: @jessehouwing - Do you think template can help here, if yes, could you please share any example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228045/discussion-between-sumit-tandon-and-jessehouwing).

Comment: No templates won't help every job needs to run the prepare and the finish step for Sonar. It sounds like your real question is: How do we speed up/diagnose the sonar issues.

Comment: @jessehouwing - is there anything in devops yml where we can run both parallel job but inside some scope so that maybe another job for sonarcloudprepare which can be shared with both of them

Comment: No there is no option to re-use the prepare step. It needs to run twice, once for each job.

Answer (score 0):

You can add sonarqube after these steps as a task. The explanation is great below! Happy coding...

https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/sonarqube/